# Log file is empty using slf4j (log4j.xml)

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, slf4j

In my project I decided to use slf4j for logging to console and file both, but my log file always left empty. Can somebody spot my mistake?
Using commons-logging everything works but inconvinient to use. 
Slf4j 1.7.25 version

UPD: The problem was resolved by changing libs in build path (slf4j-simple-1.7.25 instead of slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25)

WebPageParser.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class WebPageParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runLogger();
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebPageParser.class);
        logger.info("Application is running...");
    }

    private static void runLogger() {
        String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(projectLocation + "\\src\\Resources\\log4j.xml");
    }
}
```

log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="file"
    class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="log.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="console"
    class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

Here  is an output from debug log4j:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
log4j: root level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [log.log].
log4j: Setting property [append] to [true].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1MB].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: log.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [file] to category [root].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
```

Comment: It seems like you're not using log4j2, if you just decided you wanted to implement logging I'd recommend using log4j2 since the older version has reached end of life in 2015

Comment: Thanks, I rechecked my build path and found out that I used slf4j-simple-1.7.25 instead of slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25. The problem is resolved :)